# Can mongoose pick which db in the replicaset to query from in a single mongo connection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, replicaset

So in my app I have one mongoose connection thats connected to a replicaset db like so:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var config = "mongodb://user:password@exampleIP1:27017,exampleIP2:27017/dbName?replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=primaryPreferred"
var db = mongoose.connect(config);
```

It's primaryPreferred read and I am using mongoose to declare my schemas and query like so a million different places in the app.

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var AnalyticsScheduleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({...});
mongoose.model('AnalyticsData', AnalyticsScheduleSchema, 'AnalyticsData');
...
mongoose.model("AnalyticsData").findById(...) //read
(new mongoose.model("AnalyticsData")).save... //create
```

basically I only use the singleton mongoose instance to do CRUD to the database which is primaryPreferred read.

My question is, I have an extremely heavy map reduce operation that I want to run very frequently that can run on stale data that lags behind primary for analytics purposes. How can I switch mongoose to do reads from slaveDB only in some specific cases?

I know about methods where you can create multiple connections with different readPreferences in mongoose but it seems if I do that I can no longer query the normal way with just mongoose.model("AnalyticsData").findById... 
and would have to change all places where this happens.

Is there a way to either keep my current code working and create a new connection to secondaryPreferred or have a single connection and specify during the query whether I want to read from pimary or secondary?